# trying to copy reverse of a string using iterators?

Tags: string, iterator

This code is giving error on 7th line?
why is *it=*rit not working?

```
string temp;
string::reverse_iterator rit;
rit = demo.rbegin();
string::iterator it;
it = temp.begin();
for (; rit != demo.rend(); rit++, it++)
{
    *it = *rit;
}
```

Comment: Was any of the answer helpful to you? Feel free to [upvote & accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer why your version doesn't work.

( I don't see a definition for demo - I assume its a non-empty string. )

temp is defined though, as an empty string. 
Your loop checks "rit" but not "it" this could be OK if the 2 strings had the same length.

"it" is trying to iterate along an empty string, and that's why dereferencing it fails.

If temp was already a string with the correct length, then it could be iterated and edited successfully.

You could achieve this with

```
temp.resize(demo.length());
```

or just

```
temp = demo;
```

before the loop.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use temp.push_back(*rit); instead of the assignments

Answer (score 0):

Try it like [this](https://ideone.com/u6N1nP):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello, world";
    std::reverse_iterator<std::string::iterator> r = s.rbegin();
    std::string rev(r, s.rend());
    std::cout << rev << '\n';
}
```